# fastText WASM won't make

Tags: c++, emscripten, fasttext

I'm following the instructions to generate the WebAssembly module for fastText, and have run into an error in the `make wasm` step, as described here:

https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/webassembly-module.html

The error is

```
webassembly/fasttext_wasm.cc:178:9: error: call to deleted constructor of 'fasttext::Meter'
  Meter meter;
        ^
src/meter.h:56:3: note: 'Meter' has been explicitly marked deleted here
  Meter() = delete;
  ^
```

I'm on OSX 10.15.4. I was able to successfully build and use fastText itself. I'm not very familiar with C or web assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that needs to be fixed.

As a workaround, you can replace `Meter meter` with `Meter meter(false)` in fasttext_wasm.cc.

Thank you for reporting!

Onur

Edit: the fix is available here https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/commit/c95dd787289f9e99870cf7a1bbda1f6babd7456b